# bootstrap navbar brand image goes out of bounds

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I want the image on the top left to be perfectly centered. How do I achieve this?

Also how do I remove the gray highlight that appears(top right) whenever I click open/close a link and move away the mouse?

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-custom">
        <div class="container-fluid"> 

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#home-news-users" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <%= link_to image_tag("rnc_small.png"), home_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
            </div>


    /* Nav Bar */

    .navbar.navbar-custom {
        background-color: $light_navy;
        border-radius: 0;
        border: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
        background-color: white;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
        background-color: $light_navy;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
        border: 0;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
        color: white;   
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
        color: $rnc_orange;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .close > a,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .close > a:hover,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .close > a:active,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .close > a:focus {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:active,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: $light_navy;
      color:white;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover{
        color: $rnc_orange;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > .close > a,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > .close > a:hover,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > .close > a:active,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > .close > a:focus {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > .open > a,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > .open > a:hover,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > .open > a:active,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu > .open > a:focus {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
```

Comment: try to use vertical-align:middle;

Comment: @NelsonTan tried but didn't work. .navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
 vertical-align: middle;
}

Comment: Please share working code..

Comment: I think image is having height higher than the top bar. try setting img height to 100% or in px

Comment: @SanthoshKumar i tried this. .navbar-custom .navbar-header > a > img {
 height: 100%;
} and now it looks like this...lol. http://imgur.com/a/11c1l how do i make the image as tall as the navbar height?

Comment: @iswg check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k0sdz05o/1/

Comment: Height:100% working good. your image is small because of the padding/margin in the parent tag. If you reduce the padding you can increase the image size

Comment: If u think reducing the padding in the parent tag. Will affects other elements padding. You can still achieve by adding padding separately to the child nodes. So keeping padding lesser for image tag, Will make it larger

Comment: Still didnt achieve add that image in imgur.com, give the path of the like <img src="http://imgur.com/a/11c1l"> and create a working fiddle and share it

Comment: Use css to overcome this. For class 'navbar-brand' there is a padding hopefully it is around 15px or something. Try changing the styles for 'navbar-brand'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this [fiddle](http://%20jsfiddle.net/k0sdz05o/1)

```
.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: you sir are awesome

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following and also make image border set to 0.

```
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
   <%= link_to image_tag("rnc_small.png"), home_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
 </a>
```